# core data how do I get the value of an object that is a relation of my current object, using it's relation ship with another object

Tags: oop, core-data, entity-relationship

This is my first time using stack overflow so I'm sure I'm doing it wrong...

I have 3 entities card, play and count.

they are related as such

card <--->>count

play <<--->count

and not sure if needed but have tried  card<<--->>play

here is my situation objects in play already exist we'll say play1 play2 and play3

When I create a new card I have a textfield for newcard.
I then have a table that list all the plays from play.

newcard

play1   enter new count value
play2   enter new count value
play3   enter new count value

I am using NSManagedObject Subclasses for entities.

How do I save value to entity count with relations to the new card object and to the play object it was entered beside?

And If I use a similar setup where I already have the card object and the NSSet for related count objects and want to edit a value how do I tell it that I want to edit the object related to play3?

Oh how i wish Apple had found it in there hearts to us a primaryKey.

Let me add this since I'm sure I've lost everyone and since my background is 'older'.

If I had a primary key I would be doing this:

card(1) let's say it exist and the id is 1 or when it's created we'll have the id 1.

list of plays

play1
play2
play3      newcountvalue

I would save the new valuecountvalue along with the primary key of both card and play

newcountvalue / cardkv=1 / playkv=3.

so simple to reference and I'm sure there is something in object c or core data that will do this but for the life of me I can't find any examples or tutorials going beyond one entity related to another or one entity related to two other entities.

Comment: What code have you tried? Show it and explain what it does wrong as your current question is too broad. Show a screen shot of the core data model. Try to think in terms of objects instead of table rows and indexes.

Comment: The only code I have relates to fetching all the attributes for plays, listing them in a table with a textfield to enter the value for count. Everything works but since I will create or already have the object for card. The problem I have is how do I save that value for count to both card and play since it will be the thing that ties the two to each other. I don't have any code to do this because I don't have a clue where to begin.

Comment: You have your object classes, and they have auto-generated methods for setting the relationship contents. That's pretty much all there is to it, you just need to establish the correct relationships.

Comment: How will a record in one entity know which record in the relationship entity it is associated with if I don't tell it when saving the new object? I understand that if I open an entity as a NSSet of another entity it will know the relation but I have a third entity that also needs a relation with the new object so how do I tell the new object the value in the third entity it is related to?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a number of different entities and instances of each. Let's say that you have 2 instances from some user selection (pseudo code):

```
Card *card = ...;
Play *play = ...;
```

And that we want to insert one new entity instance:

```
Count *count = [countEntity insertNew... intoContext:...];
```

And connect up the relationships:

```
count.card = card;
play.count = count;
```

(hopefully the relationship multiplicity is correct there, but you can use the add method generated into the class instead).

Now when you save the context the relationships are also saved and when you fetch the objects in the future you can query the contents in the relationship sets.

Comment: Let me see if I get this.

Comment: Let me see if I get this. I need to have all three entities open (instance of).  I'm saving the new value for counts.  I add the value of the card I'm adjusting count values for and I'm guessing that this will set the relation in entity 'card'. And finally I set the value of count in play to set the relationship there. I don't understand how setting play.count = count will tell count which existing attribute in play to relate to. Do I have to open an instance of play that 'only' contains the value I'm relating to?

Comment: Your problem sees to be a pure oop understanding issue. You have 3 instances of entities, some fetched and some newly inserted that you are referencing to each other. Those instances have state (and the relationships are part of that state). When you save, you save the context as a whole.

Comment: I understand that the instance of card refers to the card that will relate to the other attributes. what I don't understand is this.. I have a table with each row containing one of the attributes of play in a label. so each play is listed in the table. also in the same cell I have a textfield to enter a value for count that goes to or that should be related to the play in the label in the same cell. Would I be correct in guessing that if I reference the cell that I will have the play in which I'm trying to connect.  like  cell.play.count = count

Comment: Yes. Note also that the play may already have a count so you would then update that count instance instead of creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I gave up and went old school and used ID's for card and for play. So when I created a count I would check for the id's to edit a value and would enter them when creating a value. I used NSDefaults to hold the ID values and have a simple counter class to use when creating new objects that require an id.

I know core data uses hidden id's but I'm more comfortable knowing where it is and the app actually runs with less overhead since I don't have to have an instance of all entities involved when updating or creating...

I also like sql data bases and hope that apple will someday decide to allow apps that use sqlite to use it in cloud applications.